# Is there support in log4js-node to log in AWS S3 using any appender?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, log4js-node

**Is there support in log4js-node to log in AWS S3 using any appenders?**

Answer (score -1):

I've created very basic appender for saving logs into S3.
It's called [log4js-s3-appender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-s3-appender).

You can install it with `npm i log4js-s3-appender`
and use it like that:

```js
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    s3: {
      type: "log4js-s3-appender",
      region: "eu-west-1",
      bucket: "eu-west-1-logs",
      key: "log"
    }
  },
  categories: {
    default: {
      appenders: ["s3"],
      level: "info"
    }
  }
});
```

Don't forget to call `log4js.shutdown()` to finish uploading.